# Class lacks methods after passed in Observable chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, observable

I encounter a strange problem with my custom class in angular2 after passing it through an Observable chain.

I always receive the error:

```
EXCEPTION: f.mapToParams is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: f.mapToParams is not a function
  at SafeSubscriber._next (filter.component.ts)
  ...
Uncaught TypeError: f.mapToParams is not a function
  at Safesubscriber._next (filter.component.ts)
```

Here is my coding:

filter.ts:

```
import { Params } from '@angular/router';

export class Filter {
  public text:String = '';
  public mapToParams():Params {
    let params:Params = {};
    // Do some mapping here...
    return params;
  }
}
```

filter.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Filter } from './filter';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

  private _filter:Filter;
  private _filterStream = new Subject<Filter>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this._filter = new Filter();
    this._filterStream
      .debounceTime(300)
      .switchMap((f:Filter) => Observable.of(f))
      .subscribe((f:Filter) => {
        let params:Params = {};
        console.log(f.text);            // <-- No problem here
        // params = this._map(f);          // <-- This would work
        params = f.mapToParams();       // <-- Here occurs the error
      });
  }

  private _map(f:Filter):Params {
    // Do some mapping here
  }

  public onInputChanged(searchText:String):void {
    this._mergeFilter( {
      map(f:Filter) {
        f.text = searchText;
      }
    })
  }

  private _mergeFilter(callback:FilterMergeCallback):void {
    let f:Filter = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this._filter));
    callback.map(f);
    this._filterStream.next(f);
  }

}
```

I have tried to comment out the `debounceTime` and `switchMap` statement but with no success.

At a different point in my coding the filter.mapToParams method can be called without any problems. It seems to me like the Observable chain strips all methods from my object.

Here is my angular config:

- @angular/cli: `1.0.0.-beta.32.3`
- @angular/common: `^2.4.0`
- @angular/compiler `^2.4.0`
- @angular/core `^2.4.0`
- rxjs: `^5.1.0`

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Please see above. Have added some more error statements.

Comment: How does the code look like where you emit a value using `_filterStream`? (also `new subject<Filter>()` should be `new Subject<Filter>()` with uppercase `S`)

Comment: new subject with lowercase s was a typo... I will add some more coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

I copied the current _filter Object to a new filter variable by

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())
```

By this, all methods get stripped from the new object.

Means, I have to find a new method to clone the object...

Thanks all for you replies!